# Video is not showing up in ios os

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, vue.js

i have an up loader that uploads the video which is working on all devices and OS but not the iPhone ether the chrome or safari fails to open the video any idea what might be wrong because i checked net and i came up with this solution : in ios the player loads but it does not shows the video with the below solution

```
<video class="video" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
```

i did this yet no luck . this is the link i am trying to play video on ios :

```
https://wishato.com/wish/wStvun
```

here is my code for video :

```
<template>
    <div class="wishgallery">
        <loading :display="loading"></loading>
        <div class="gallery" v-show="dataLoaded">
            <transition-group name="wish-gallery"
                              tag="div"
                              class="gallery-items"
                              :enter-active-class="enterClass"
                              :leave-active-class="leaveClass">
                <div v-for="(item) in slideShow" :key="item.id" class="gallery-item"
                     v-show="item.active">

                    <img v-if="item.mime.match('image')" :src="item.path" alt="wishato" v-on:load="imgLoaded($event)">
                    <video class="video" controls v-else-if="item.mime=='video/mp4'" poster="">
                        <source :src="item.path" :type="item.mime">
                        your browser cant support this format 
                    </video>
                </div>
            </transition-group>
            <div class="navigator" v-if="slideShow.length > 1" :class="[{hidenavigator: navStat}]">
                <span class="hideIcon" @click="hidenav">
                    <i class="icon icon-chevron-down"></i>
                </span>
                <div class="nav-items">
                    <div class="nav-cont">
                        <div v-for="(item) in slideShow" :key="item.id" class="nav-item"
                             :class="{active : item.active}" @click="changeImage(item.id)">
                            <img v-if="item.mime.match('image')" :src="item.path" alt="wishato"
                                 v-on:load="imgLoaded($event)">
                            <div class="video" v-else-if="item.mime.match('video')">
                                <i class="icon icon-playvideo"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Have you checked your network tab, is there an error with the video? Are there any warnings or error in your browser console?

Comment: no nothing really because it works cool on chrome windows and andriod